# Codeacademy contact list building 7/8... Not returning contact info

Tags: javascript

i'm doing the codeacademy class section "building a contact list" .. what is wrong here? keep getting error "Oops, try again. It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Steve."
(http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-3bmfN/0/7)

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
    firstName: "Bill",
    lastName: "Gates",
    number: "(206) 555-5555",
    address: ['One Microsoft Way', 'Redmond', 'WA', '98052']
};
friends.steve = {
    firstName: "Steve",
    lastName: "Jobs",
    number: "(556) 555-5555",
    address: ['178 martio', 'cocoa', 'CA', '95074']
};
var list = function(friends) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        console.log(key);
    }
};
var search = function(friends) {
    for (var key in friends) {
        if (friends[key].firstName === "Bill" || friends[key].firstName === "Steve") {
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        } else {
            console.log("couldn't find them");
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in the search function:

The instructions tell you:

> Define a function search that takes a single argument, name. If the
>   argument passed to the function matches any of the first names in
>   friends, it should log that friend's contact information to the
>   console and return it.

In a nutshell, it is asking you to create a function where you provide the **name** of the person you are searching, while you are providing **friends** which is also a **global variable**.

The goal of the exercice seems to be that by using:

```
search("steve");
```

you should get as a result:

```
Object :
{ firstName: 'Steve',
  lastName: 'Jobs',
  number: '(556) 555-5555',
  address: [ '178 martio', 'cocoa', 'CA', '95074' ] }
```

In your (current) search function you will get a result not from the needle (the search parameter) but from your own preferences, defined in your if condition:

```
if (friends[key].firstName === "Bill" || friends[key].firstName === "Steve")
```

Hence, what we are going to do, is:

- set **name** as parameter
- loop the **friends** global variable
- check if friends[key].firstName is **equal to the needle provided** (name).
- if so, we **log it** and **return it**.

Put all together:

```
var search = function(name) { // <-- note the name instead of friends.
    for (var key in friends) {
        if (friends[key].firstName === name) { // <-- note that if
            console.log(friends[key]);
            return friends[key];
        } else {
            console.log("couldn't find them");
        }
    }
};
```

And you're done!

http://prntscr.com/7kth5t
[image]

Good try anyway, you were pretty close to the solution.
If you still have any problem or need any clarification feel free to comment.

Comment: omg thank you thank you thank you! lol  I have a question though. Why would I use 'function(name)' if I set the names with 'firstName' .... how would the computer know that "Steve" is the name if I am not telling it to look for firstName specifically?

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how does the computer know "Steve" is the name? does that question make sense? thanks so much for your help I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @karmadreamwalker: the scope of the search function is to find something inside the **friends** variable: you currently don't see that in codeacademy, but in order to actually execute the **search** function you have to execute it, and you do that by doing: `search("somename");`. The scope of the function, in a nutshell, is that if you write: `search("bill");` it needs to tell you the information about **bill** and, if someday, you will add "karl" to your **friends** object by writing: `search("karl");` it will post the informations about karl, get it?

Comment: In any case, the "computer" (in this case is the compiler) doesn't know neither who steve is, nor who bill is, it is you (the user) that by providing an input (in this case the string "steve") you ask to your javascript code to **find** (using the **search function**) something inside the **friends** variable with **steve** as **firstname** property, the scope of that function is to use it later and be able to access data by giving a specific parameter (in this case the name, that **you** [the programmer] define in the **function**) :)

Comment: Also, the variable "name" is a placeholder: you could've put **function(hello)** and set in the if: `if (friends[key].firstName === hello) ` that it would've been the exact same: the `name` parameter of that function is the placeholder that holds the variable put inside the search function when you call it. In such a case, though, it makes sense to call it **name**, since you are effectively looking for a name, but it's up to you to choose the variable names ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use for listing:

```
list(friends);
```

and for search:

```
search(friends);
```